# How to get the max of a sublist?

Tags: python, list

I try to discover the error here:

```
for list in result:
        print(sorted(list, key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[0])
```

considering that list = [['cat1', 0.0],['cat2', 0.487],['cat3', 0.89]     ... ]

when I run the code i have this error:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

any Help ?

Comment: you made a mistake `list` is a internal keyword. change variable to something else.

Comment: @VikashSingh `list` is not a keyword, it's merely a built-in type.

Comment: @VikashSingh I think you mean to say that list is a **_builtin_** keyword. Using `list` as a variable won't raise any errors by itself, but it is bad practice.

Comment: I have rename it by res ... but the same error appears

Comment: @ElBaFatima So let me make sure where on the same page. You want to get the maximum element of each sublist in `result`?

Comment: @ElBaFatima probably Bendik's answer does what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me your trying to sort your 2d list, not find the max value. Assuming that, you can use a lambda to sort your 2d list by the first element of each sublist using the `key` keyword:

```
>>> result = [['cat1', 0.0],['cat2', 0.487],['cat3', 0.89]]
>>> sorted(result, key=lambda sublist: sublist[1], reverse=True)[0]
['cat3', 0.89]
>>>
```

Comment: I try with lambda , and I get this error again : 
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

Comment: That's funny, this works for me. Could you post what your `results` list looks like exactly.

Comment: this is my list ( no result ) [['CAT1', 0.033], ['CAT2', 0.044], ['CAT3', 0.5], ['CAT4', 0.02], ['CAT5', 0.0]] ..

Comment: My solution works with your sample list as well. Perhaps you didn't copy my code verbatim, and should just try copy 'n pasting again.

Comment: Yes, Yes you right .. sorry I did't copy your code rightly it's works thank you again

Answer (score 0):

You could apply the sorting with your key function to your outer list, but you are applying it to each of the inner lists:

```
for list in result:
    # now list is e.g ['cat1', 0.0]
    print(sorted(list, key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[0])
```

This will apply `itemgetter(1)` to each element in list, hence `itemgetter(1)(0.0)` will fail and raise the error that you see as it is the same as `0.0[1]`.

The key function is applied to list elements and the result of said call is used for comparison with other elements. You could, however, do:

```
print(sorted(result, key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[0])
```

Comment: I make a mistake it's not result = [['cat1', 0.0],['cat2', 0.487],['cat3', 0.89] ... ] but  list = [['cat1', 0.0],['cat2', 0.487],['cat3', 0.89] ... ]

Comment: then what is result?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
print(sorted(result, key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[0])
```

i.e. no loop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that right now you are sorting your second list, e.g.: `['cat1', 0.0]`. However you are really trying to sort the `result` list. So you could do the following, using a lambda expression:

```
>>> sorted_list = sorted(result, key=lambda cat: cat[1], reverse=True)

>>> sorted_list
[['cat3', 0.89], ['cat2', 0.487], ['cat1', 0.0]]
```

Notice that `cat` here is your sublist, and the key you are sorting by is your sublists second value `cat[1]`